# Можно ли создать незакрываемое окно в android? Как это сделать?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-layout

Всем здравствуйте! Нужно создать окно, которое не закрывается вручную - Только автоматически. То есть я выхожу из приложения, а окно будет всегда открыто, даже если я нажму кнопку "Домой". В приложении tasker так можно сделать с помощью overlay blocking. Как это сделать в моём приложении? Вот исходный код, который создаёт окно:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button btnClosePopup;
Button btnCreatePopup;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnCreatePopup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btnCreatePopup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            initiatePopupWindow();
        }
    });

}

private PopupWindow pwindo;

private void initiatePopupWindow() {
    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
        pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        btnClosePopup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.close_popup);
        btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pwindo.dismiss();
    }
};
```

}
Код popup.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/HiText"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_marginTop="5sp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/CloseText"
    android:id="@+id/close_popup"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Код activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnText"
    android:id="@+id/button" />
```

[image: Код popup.xml]

[image: Код activity_main.xml]

Сверху код popup.xml.
Снизу код activity_main.xml.
Скажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: Решение ответа есть тут - http://ita2010.psu.ru:81/blogs/opblog/83/ точно такой же вопрос разбирается

Comment: это работало на старых версиях андроида, до 2-3 где-то. После стало невозможно отследить кнопку домой (сворачивает все приложения), дальнейшие развития идеи ведёт в малозаконные дебри с администраторами устройства, fictus - аналогами и так далее.

Comment: @madJerico Спасибо, попробую!